# Asynctask is not executing serially with AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask

Here is my code, please have a look

```
                  for (Fragment fragment : alFragments) {

                            AddViewAsync addViewAsync = new AddViewAsync(fragment, currentValue);

                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                                addViewAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
                            else
                                addViewAsync.execute();

                        }
```

and the asynctask is given below, i am executing them in loop and want to execute one by one

```
 private class AddViewAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Object currentValue;
    private Fragment fragment;

    public AddViewAsync(Fragment fragment, Object currentValue) {
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ((IUpdateInFragment) fragment).addEventOnView(currentValue);
        if(!isCancelled()){
          cancel(true)  ;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: facing any error?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error but all threads are executing parallely instead of sequentially